# How does Salesforce handle wildcards in a REST urlmapping property

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have a question about the urlmapping property on a REST class. For the moment I have 3 REST classes with following urlmappings:

1. REST1.cls @RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/')
2. REST2.cls @RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/totals/')
3. REST3.cls @RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/related/')

I have 3 types of corresponding REST urls:

1. "/services/apexrest/invoices/due/" or "/services/apexrest/invoices/paid/"
2. "/services/apexrest/invoices/{Salesforce Id}/totals/"
3. "/services/apexrest/invoices/{Salesforce Id}/related/"

When I do the requests I get the following results:

- CORRECT "/services/apexrest/invoices/due/" maps to REST1.cls
- CORRECT "/services/apexrest/invoices/paid/" maps to REST1.cls
- INCORRECT "/services/apexrest/invoices/{Salesforce Id}/totals/" maps to REST1.cls (should map to REST2.cls)
- INCORRECT "/services/apexrest/invoices/{Salesforce Id}/related/" maps to REST1.cls (should map to REST3.cls)

When I look at the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_rest220/Content/asynch_api_rest.htm) I see that these are the rules followed:

> - An exact match always wins.
> - If no exact match is found, find all the patterns with wildcards that match, and then select the longest (by string length) of those.
> - If no wildcard match is found, an HTTP response status code 404 is returned.

**I would expect they map to the classes listed above. Can someone
explain what is going wrong here?**

**UPDATE**:
I want to keep the logic of my REST url's, the sequence of the parameters and url structure is in line with usability best practises, and I believe the salesforce url mapping should be capable of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*EDITED*: It works **sometimes without any problem** (even with the oldest Api 22.0 that supports RestResource) and **sometimes incorrectly**.

That **depends** on the order of classes sorted by the **time of the last modification**.

If you edit the class REST1.cls or generally that with the shortest urlMapping length (add a comment into) it starts to work as you expect.

It is not exactly incorrect, because **`*`** matches any string with **any number of `/`**. It seems that the text "the patterns with wildcards... select the longest (by string length)" should be understand only "the longest string **before** the wildcard". The order of compared matching is not explicitely defined by docs if these parts are the same.
They mean only: `/word/*` is a longer and better match than `/*`.

They want to provide a fast service. Therefore they probably need firstly to do a coarse match by an index, then to try classes ordered by this index until the first match is found. If you can find a good index expression than it can be probably fixed, but it is much complicated by rules about the final slash. I'm skeptical of anything, except for asking a possible very small improvement in documentation.

Tested code exemples:
REST1

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/')
global class REST1 {
    @HttpGet
    global static String getClassName() {
        return 'REST1';
    }
}
```

REST2

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/totals/')
global class REST2 {
    @HttpGet
    global static String getClassName() {
        return 'REST2';
    }
}
```

REST3

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*/related/')
global class REST3 {
    @HttpGet
    global static String getClassName() {
        return 'REST3';
    }
}
```

---

It is better and more universal to use `urlMapping` string without the final slash, but is is not important for this question. Example:

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/invoices/*')
```

It can catch both `/invoices/something/` and `/invoices/something`, while the mapping with the final slash requires only this one. Every example in Apex docs (e.g. [the qouted above](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_rest220/Content/asynch_api_rest.htm)) is without any final slash.

**EDITED ** because the problem was not initially reproducible.

Comment: Removing the trailing slashes does not solve the problem. I also tested REST2 and REST3 by removing one and then the other. They both work on their own but not together. I just need to find out how the internal matching works so I can understand what I can do and what not. But thanks!

Comment: @stvnhg Yes. It behaves randomly. I still know how.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke: I edited my answer for the last time, about the background of question, in the 4th and 5th paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not clear but I believe that it will match

urlmapping='/invoices/*/

over

urlmapping='/invoices/*/totals/

This is because the wildcard character is not at the end. To fix this issue, you might have to vary your url format for REST2 and 3 to the following.

urlmapping='/invoices/totals/*

urlmapping='/invoices/related/*

This means that your url will be:

/invoices/totals/{salesforceId}

/invoices/related/{salesforceId}

Comment: This will probably work but then I would need to change the logic in my rest url's, which I do not want to do. What you are suggesting are not discoverable url's. Can you explain the internal matching? Thanks!